# "variable" cumulative value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id   count   price
1    100      2
2    50       3
3    10       4
```

I want to get the price for certain cumulative count values, for instance: 
when I "need" a count of 120, SQL cumulates the first x rows, and checks if the the cumulative value in the x'th row meets the requirements (>120) and then gives me back the price value of the x'th row.

For 120 I want to get 3 as price, for 159.5 then 4, for 80 a 2 etc.

Is that possible in SQL Server?

Comment: What does "when i query 120" mean?

Comment: You want the price corresponding to the value (or sum of values) that is closest to your "variable" ? (That was even hard to ask a question about...)

Comment: i updated my post, sorry if it was unclear, i hope its better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you want this:

```
select   top 1
         [price]
from(
select  [id],
        [count],
        [price],
        sum([count]) over(order by [id]) as run_sum
from    tbl
) x
where    120 <= run_sum
order by run_sum
```

**Fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1976/5/0

Fiddle example for 159.5, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1976/6/0

Fiddle example for 80, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1976/7/0

Comment: Thank you, it works! I think your query works faster then the below one? (i want to query it several thousand times in a short time)

Comment: Np, it only accesses the table once because of the analytic function (no join back to the same table) so it should be a little faster

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 price from
(
    select t1.id, t1.count, SUM(t2.count) as sum, t1.price
    from table_name t1
    inner join table_name t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
    group by t1.id, t1.count, t1.price
) t where t.sum >= 120 order by sum
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78ebb/1)